# phpmailer - undefined letters in the body

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use the PHPMailer as my mail tool for a project. I should send to a user a letter which contains Romanian alphabet (the main difference from English letters is the fact of issue such letters as â, ă, î, ș, ț).

I set charset UTF-8 for my letter:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

but it didn't help me. I see in Google mail signs ? instead â, ă, î, ș or ț.

How can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through is a good read.

Comment: That's the right thing to set in PHPMailer, but you may be giving it data in an ISO8859 charset.